# Save to and retrieve from local storage with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I currently have an application that stores and updates a single value from an input field. However, I need it to save from multiple inputs, as an object I guess but I have no clue on how to do this. Any help on how to do this would be appreciated.

My HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="newtripController as d">
    <input ng-model="d.startKm" value={{d.startKm}}/>
    <input ng-model="d.stopKm" value={{d.stopkm}}/>
    <input type="button" value="update" ng-click="d.update(d.startKm)" />
</div>
```

My controller:

```
angular.module("app").controller("newtripController",
    [
        "newtripService",function (newtripService){
            this.startKm = newtripService.getData();
            this.latestData = function(){
                return newtripService.getData();
            };
        this.update = function(val){
            return newtripService.setData(val);
            };
        }
    ]);
```

My service:

```
angular.module("app").factory("newtripService",
    function($window, $rootScope){
        angular.element($window).on("storage",
            function(event) {
                if(event.key === "trip") {
                    $rootScope.$apply();
                }
            });
        return {
            setData: function(val) {
                localStorage.setItem("trip", val);
                return this;
            },
            getData: function() {
                return localStorage.getItem("trip");
            }
        };
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you just save the entire object?

```
angular.module('app').controller('newtripController',
[
    'newtripService',function (newtripService){
        this.trip = newtripService.getData();
    this.update = function(val){
        return newtripService.setData(this.trip);
        };
    }
]);

<div ng-controller="newtripController as d">
    <input ng-model="d.trip.startKm" value={{d.trip.startKm}}/>
    <input ng-model="d.trip.stopKm" value={{d.trip.stopkm}}/>
    <input type="button" value="update" ng-click="d.update()" />
<div>
```

I haven't tested this, so not sure if it works straight as it is, you might need to stringify it before you save the object, and then json parse it when you retrieve it. That would look like:

```
 angular.module('app').controller('newtripController',
[
    'newtripService',function (newtripService){
        this.trip = JSON.parse(newtripService.getData());
    this.update = function(val){
        return newtripService.setData(JSON.stringify(this.trip));
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, I just wasn't sure on how to do it. I had to use the parse and stringify version. Thanks, pal.

Answer (score 1):

For Set Data

```
localStorage.setItem("trip", val);
```

For Get Data

```
localStorage.getItem("trip");
```